# Google OCR incorrect text detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision

[image]

I'm using Google AI to get gext from image. It is using DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTTION,
but the data is incorrect.

Do you have any suggestion?

[Update]
expected result should be:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with your language, could you please elaborate what the issue is, exactly? The symbols in the two pictures appears to be the same.

Comment: I updated the content for the expected result

Comment: Use Vis2 or Capture2Text.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for you to either:

1. Submit a Public report on [Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) since OCR issues are better supported there. (Recommended)
2. Update your question with your request process; JSON, Client Library or API as
   in [Detect text in images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr).

Note that [Supported Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) are subject to these [File formats](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#file_formats), [Image sizing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#image_sizing) and [File size](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#file_size).